# Windows 7 cmd, from Visual Studio, not displaying floats

Tags: python, c++, cmd, visual-studio-2015, floating-point

In Visual Studio 2015, I made a program to calculate pi. The variable for pi is `float` (I wasn't sure if this was really necessary but I thought I might as well just in case), anyway.. Here's the function:

```
float pi(int accuracy) {
    float pi = 3;
    int nint = 2;
    int next;
    for (int i = 0; i < accuracy; i++) {
        next = 4 / (nint * (nint + 1) * (nint + 2));
        nint += 2;
        if (i % 2 == 0) {
            pi += next;
        }
        else {
            pi -= next;
        }
    }
    return pi;
}
```

So as far as I can see, this should return a `float` variable. When I call it, I use `2000` as the parameter, and this should return quite an accurate representation of pi. Visual Studio displays this to cmd, but instead of writing any decimal places, it just shows `3`.
I then decided to test this in Python. Here's the code:

```
pi = 3
n_int = 2

# I'm using 1000 as the accuracy, because Python's slower.
for i in range(1000):
    nextint = 4 / (n_int * (n_int + 1) * (n_int + 2))
    n_int += 2
    if i % 2 == 0:
        pi += nextint
    else:
        pi -= nextint

print(pi)
input()
```

I tested it with Python because this way there was two different ways of outputting the number. First, I ran it directly from IDLE, which displayed the output in an IDLE window. This displayed `3.141592653340544` (This isn't entirely accurate, but is expected). But when I double-click the Python file in Windows Explorer (making it open in cmd), and then it only displays `3`, just like with the c++ example.
From this I can fairly safely say that it's a problem with cmd, perhaps I've changed some setting or something which might make this happen (although I can't remember doing this).
So, how, in cmd, can I display a float or long number?

Comment: How are you displaying it?

Comment: @immibis `cout << pi(2000);`

Comment: Check your file association with .py (which Windows Explorer will use). I suspect that is linked to Python 2 but your IDLE is Python 3.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`next = 4 / (nint * (nint + 1) * (nint + 2));`

`(nint * (nint + 1) * (nint + 2))` is an `int`. 4 is an `int`. Dividing two `int`s gives you another `int`, by removing the decimal part (because `int`s have no decimal parts).

You should change this to `4.0` or `4.0f` to use floating-point division.

And then you should make `next` a `float` or a `double`, because the number it needs to store isn't a whole number.

Comment: This worked - thanks, I didn't realize that it would give an int

Comment: I'll accept the answer as soon as I can, it's not letting me this soon

Comment: Also, with the Python code it returns it to a lot more decimal places than the C++ one. Why's this? (This is after changing all the variables to doubles) - I'm using the same algorithm in both

Answer (score 0):

"The variable for pi is long long" - that's likely your problem right there.  `long long` is an integer type. It can't store a floating point number like pi. Use a `float`, `double` or `long double`.

Comment: The asker says that, but I don't see `long long` in any of the code.

Comment: @Jesper Juhl yes, in the code it's actually a float, I didn't realise when I typed it

Comment: @immibis I assumed that's what he used to store the result of a call to `pi()` in. But of course it's impossible to know without seeing a complete code example.